Robot arm movement
First of all, good work everyone. I'm working on a robot arm. My goal is to keep the hand always steady. Now when I give a movement from the shoulder, I read them with the help of a gyroscope. This gives me the roll pitch and yaw value in euler. But there is also the angle at the elbow. If this angle is different from 0, the shoulder pitch behaves just like roll. How can I calculate this? It is very easy to calculate only the pitch movement without taking roll into account.
Tan(vertical) = Tan(pitch) + cos(alpha)
alpha here is the angle at the joint. But when roll comes into play, things get completely complicated.
How can I solve this problem, that is, how can I take into account the movement of the roll? But in this case, the length does not matter, I just want to use the angles.

Hi. I think it would really, really, really help if you drew the robot arm, with vertical, pitch and alpha and other relevant things highlighted.

Also note your actual question is a bit hard to figure out. Sentences like "How can I solve this problem?" and "How can I calculate this?" are not helping readers figure out what it is exactly that you want to calculate. I also don't know what the statement "pitch behaves like roll" means.

when the angle at the joint is greater than 0, the pitch value at the shoulder acts like a roll for the part after the joint. that's what I wanted to talk about. I used the vertical meaning as the amount it should move vertically. so we can say EL.

Could you please add an image to show all that?
